# Update record then delete

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update one record and then delete another in one go, however it's only allowing me to do one or the other;

```
$update = "UPDATE user SET felcredits = '$value' WHERE username = '$user'";
$update2 = "DELETE FROM playeritems WHERE id = '$realid'";
```

How do I get it to do both?
I have tried the following;

```
$update = "UPDATE user SET felcredits = '$value' WHERE username = '$user'";
$update = "DELETE FROM playeritems WHERE id = '$realid'";
```

__

```
$update = "UPDATE user SET felcredits = '$value' WHERE username = '$user' DELETE FROM playeritems WHERE id = '$realid'";
```

__

FULL CODE:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = $_POST AND isset($_POST['sell'])) {
$sql = "SELECT felcredits FROM user WHERE username = '$user'";
$result = $db_conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $felcredits = $row['felcredits'];
    }
}
$value = $felcredits + $value;
$update = "UPDATE user SET felcredits = '$value' WHERE username = '$user'";
$update2 = "DELETE FROM playeritems WHERE id = '$realid'";
if ($db_conn->query($update) === TRUE) {
    echo "<br />Details Updated";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $insert . "<br>" . $db_conn->error;
}
```

}

Comment: just do it on separate executions

Comment: Show your full code.

Comment: Full code added to the bottom

Comment: Use parameterized queries first, this is open to SQL injections as is. To execute multiple queries in `mysqli` you need to use the `multi-query` function and separate the queries with semi-colons. You are only executing `$update` currently, you do nothing with `$update2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Try change in Your full code Like this

in your Execute code

---

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = $_POST AND isset($_POST['sell'])) {
 $sql = "SELECT felcredits FROM user WHERE username = '$user'";
$result = $db_conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $felcredits = $row['felcredits'];
}
}       
$value = $felcredits + $value;
$update = "UPDATE user SET felcredits = '$value' WHERE username = '$user'";
$update2 = "DELETE FROM playeritems WHERE id = '$realid'";
if (($db_conn->query($update) === TRUE) && ($db_conn->query($update2) ===     TRUE)) {
echo "<br />Details Updated";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $insert . "<br>" . $db_conn->error;
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here:

```
$update = "UPDATE user SET felcredits = '$value' WHERE username = '$user'";
$update = "DELETE FROM playeritems WHERE id = '$realid'";
```

your second sql query will override the first one, so make separate query like:

```
$update = "UPDATE user SET felcredits = '$value' WHERE username = '$user'";
mysqli_query($conn, $update);

$delete = "DELETE FROM playeritems WHERE id = '$realid'";
mysqli_query($conn, $delete);
```

where $conn is the connection handle

Comment: This should be the accepted answer and not the answer above.

Comment: @Ronald its OK, may be Kamata is more comfortable with the above one